# log4j2 does not read spring boot property from correct configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties, log4j2

In log4j2.xml I have the following 2 properties:

```
<Properties>
<Property name="log-path">logs</Property>
<Property name="bootstrap.servers" value="${bundle:application:app.kafkaBrokers}"></Property>
<Property name="fileName" value="${bundle:application:app.correctName}"></Property>
```

And the following two appenders:

```
<Kafka name="Kafka" topic="logaggregation" >
  <JSONLayout complete="false" compact="false" /> <PatternLayout pattern="%date %message" /> 
  <Property name="bootstrap.servers">${bootstrap.servers}</Property>
</Kafka>
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${fileName}"
  filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
  <PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
  <Policies>
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB" />
  </Policies>
</RollingFile>
```

kafkaAppender reads the property

> bootstrap.servers

and Rolling file reads the property

> fileName

Inside my src/main/resources I have the following application.properties file:

```
app.kafkaBrokers=localhost:9092
```

app.correctName=log.txt

Inside the folder that the jar is located I have another application.properties file with the following contents:

app.kafkaBrokers=localhost:9092
app.correctName=correct.log

Now if I run with java -jar my springboot jar log4j2 does not get the property from the file which resides inside the directory where the jar file is, as stated in the spring documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

The fact is that if I write the following code in my main class:

```
  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    System.out.println(env.getProperty("app.kafkaBrokers") + "  "
        + env.getProperty("app.correctName"));

  }
```

I see the printed the correct values such as "correct.log" but still log4j2 does not get the new value and uses "log.txt"

What I suspect is that log4j2 starts before spring actually pick up the correct application.properties file.
Any ideas?

Comment: ${ } looks missed in case of bundle:env:kafkaBrokers

Comment: that was a typo. thanks though